# Does omitting the first two lines of RC4's pseudo-random generation algorithm weaken the cipher?

Tags: implementation, rc4

A particular educational software program published by a U.S. government agency uses a variant of RC4 to obfuscate its data files (see [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334944/how-can-i-defeat-rc4-like-obfuscation)). The variant of RC4 in question is identical to standard RC4 except at the beginning of the pseudo-random generation algorithm. The developer omitted the first two lines below (from [Wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#The_pseudo-random_generation_algorithm_.28PRGA.29)) because he based his code on an [erroneous implementation](http://web.archive.org/web/20100605102558/http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1736&lngWId=1) from Planet Source Code from around 2005.

```
i := 0
j := 0
while GeneratingOutput:
    i := (i + 1) mod 256
    j := (j + S[i]) mod 256
    swap values of S[i] and S[j]
    K := S[(S[i] + S[j]) mod 256]
    output K
endwhile
```

Thus, `i` and `j` retain their final values from when the key scheduling algorithm ran (`i = 256`, not `0`, and `j = (j + S[i] + key[i mod keylength]) mod 256` from when `i = 255` during the KSA).

In this case, the encryption provides no actual security because the key is hardcoded into the software, but suppose the developer had used the code to encrypt a secret file on his hard drive. Does this implementation error significantly weaken RC4's strength?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**, that omission weakens the cipher: the output  $\mathtt K$ has a short cycle (at most 65280 bytes) for a sizable class of keys (one in 65536). The following details why.

Because earlier code leaves $\mathtt i=256$ and the first execution of `i := (i + 1) mod 256` makes that equivalent to $\mathtt i=0$, not initializing $\mathtt i$ makes no difference in subsequent code; and hence has no security implication whatsoever.

But earlier code leaves $\mathtt j$ to a key-dependent value, thus the lack of initialization of $\mathtt j$ has an effect. In particular, if at the end of key scheduling $\mathtt j=1$ and $\mathtt S[1]=1$, then (by induction) during the whole of the stream generation we have $\mathtt j=(\mathtt i+1)\bmod 256$ and $\mathtt S[\mathtt j]=1$; thus the output generated has a short cycle of (at most) $256\cdot 255$ bytes.
This never occurs in real RC4 (as observed in 1994 by Hal Finney, in [An RC4 cycle that can't happen](https://groups.google.com/group/sci.crypt/msg/175368a41b44e99d?dmode=source&output=gplain&noredirect), summarized on the [RC4 page](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~itsik/RC4/rc4.html)), but occurs for $2^{-16}$ of the keys in the modified cipher.